# ERR_REQUIRE_ESM for import with @xenova/transformers

Tags: node.js, typescript, huggingface-transformers

In my NodeJS app I import like this:

```
import { AutoModel, AutoTokenizer } from '@xenova/transformers';
```

And then use it like so:

```
const tokenizer = await AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased');
```

However when I run my script I get this:

```
> node --experimental-modules lib/index.js

No storage option exists to persist the session, which may result in unexpected behavior when using auth.
        If you want to set persistSession to true, please provide a storage option or you may set persistSession to false to disable this warning.
Starting script...
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/me/Projects/node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/transformers.js from /home/me/Projects/lib/pinecone/utils.js not supported.
Instead change the require of transformers.js in /home/me/Projects/lib/pinecone/utils.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at /home/me/Projects/lib/pinecone/utils.js:34:81
    at async syncProfilesOnPinecone (/home/me/Projects//lib/pinecone/utils.js:34:33)
    at async main (/home/me/Projects/lib/index.js:9:5) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Not sure what to do?

Comment: It says right in the error message. If your project is compiled down to CJS and you have a dependency on an ESM-only package you must use a dynamic import. That or change your project to ESM, or find a CJS variant of your dependency.

Comment: @morganney I tried a dynamic import: `const moduleA = await import('@xenova/transformers');` but same issue

Answer (score 6):

Creator of Transformers.js here.

This is a problem not specific to transformers.js (for the most part), and occurs because of your node resolution settings in tsconfig.json. By default, all `import` statements are converted to `require` during compilation.

You can fix this as follows:

```js
TransformersApi = Function('return import("@xenova/transformers")')();
const { pipeline } = await TransformersApi;
```

which basically just delays the import to after compilation. See [here](https://github.com/xenova/transformers.js/issues/80#issuecomment-1638773862) for more information.